# Persist headers like user-agent and referer when auto redirect is true for httpurlconnection in java

Tags: java, redirect, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpUrlConnection class in java to make http requests.
The auto-redirect property is set to true using setInstanceFollowRedirect.
I am setting headers like User-Agent and referer in the initial request. The same can't be found in the redirection request. How can I persist the values of the headers like User-Agent and referer for all the requests when the auto-redirect property is set to true.